# How to use a Geyser plugin

Tags: geyser

I want to periodically sync a set of accounts from a validator to my database and I find Geyser plugins fit my need. But the [document](https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins) doesn't show how to attach the plugin to a running validator or something.

What do I suppose to do with a Geyser plugin against a validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A validator can run with a companion geyser plugin as such:

```
solana-test-validator --geyser-plugin-config my_plugin_config.json
```

At minima, the validator needs to know the path to the dynamic library. Indeed at startup the validator will try to find your geyser plugin library and `dlopen()` it. So here's the minimum valid JSON file:

```
{
  "libpath": "path_to_lib/libmy_geyser_plugin.so"
}
```

#### 1 Simple Geyser Plugin Example

**Here's a starter project you can use to make your geyser plugin: https://github.com/mwrites/solana-geyser-plugin-scaffold**

#### 2 Regarding [solana-accountsdb-plugin-postgres](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-accountsdb-plugin-postgres)

The configuration file requires more than just **"libpath"**, prepare your Postgres DB accordingly and with the correct information most importantly:

- `host`
- `user`
- `port`

For `libpath`, run `cargo build`, and assuming you are on MacOS (for dev), the path is most probably `./target/debug/libsolana_geyser_plugin_postgres.dylib`. Note the **.dylib** on MacOS.

Answer (score 3):

Look [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins#the-plugin-interface), specifically

> The plugin configuration file is specified by the validator's CLI parameter --geyser-plugin-config and the file must be readable to the validator process.